# How to resolve dependency in asp.net mvc when can only access Interfaces and don't have access to implementation classes of them

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

**I have injected(AccountAccessInterface) interface in the constructor when I run API I can't resolve its dependency as this interface I am getting from .dll and don't have access to its implementation. So I need some way so that I can resolve dependency   inside controller in any way Please as without having implementation(hidden implementation) class of interface I face error in APIs of dependency resolver**

[image]

```
public class AdminController : ApiController
{
    private readonly AccountAccessInterface _accountAccessInterface;

    public AdminController(AccountAccessInterface accountAccessInterface)
    {
        _accountAccessInterface = accountAccessInterface;
    }


    // to get account if by user id
   [Route("api/admin/ProcessTrsanctionAndSave")]
   [HttpGet]
    public void ProcessTrsanctionAndSave()
    {


        BankDB.BankDB bankDB = new BankDB.BankDB();
        bankDB.ProcessAllTransactions();
        bankDB.SaveToDisk();
    }
}
```

Comment: If `AccountAccessInterface` isn't designed to be injected, dependency injection won't help you. Acquire the interface in the way one usually would (whatever that may be) and if necessary wrap your implementation with code that declares an interface suitable for DI

Answer (score 2):

The Dependency service can only resolve services it is provided, it cannot magically create one for you.

If you cannot create an instance of the class you're trying to resolve through the interface then I'm afraid there's nothing you can do.

However, if you can instantiate the class then you can create a wrapper around it and pass that to the dependency service.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the problem by doing the Following work.
**When we don't have access to implementation class it means interfaces are returning from any class as a method.so if we do**
[image]

**TransactionAccessInterface is interface here and Models.Globoclass.myBank.GetTransactionInterface() is the base class from interface returning as method.**

```
 public object SelectTransaction(uint TransactionID)
    {
        TransactionAccessInterface myint = Models.Globoclass.myBank.GetTransactionInterface();
        myint.SelectTransaction(TransactionID);
        Transaction_Details transaction_Details = new Transaction_Details();
        transaction_Details.amount = myint.GetAmount();
        transaction_Details.recvrAccount = myint.GetRecvrAcct();
        transaction_Details.sendrAmount = myint.GetSendrAcct();

        return transaction_Details;
    }
```